# Arrow keys are shown by some weird characters everywhere

Tags: bugs, fonts

In my Android device, arrow keys are shown by some weird characters everywhere. Example:

[image]

I have tried changing system fonts. Also, this is independent of the keyboard because I have changed the keyboard but the issue is not resolved.

Edit:: ij acts as  UP key, IJ acts as LEFT key, 'n acts as  RIGHT key and ' acts ad DOWN key.

Comment: Cross-post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/g45vc0/weird_arrow_keys_everywhere_in_my_android_device/), in case it's answered on there.

Comment: Anyway, in case it may help, some shown characters are: [ĳ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0133/index.htm), [Ĳ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0132/index.htm)

Comment: I have already posted on reddit but haven't got any working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fix, but Internet search results ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865402/unicode-problem-with-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567146/unicode-character-on-android-not-displaying)) give me the impression your issue is caused by lacking Unicode support in the fonts you've tried so far, although that would be strange for something as generic as arrow symbols. As such, my only suggestion is to try yet more fonts if you are able to do that. I doubt I can provide more help than that, but you could add some more info about your issue:

- Have you seen these symbols display correctly on your device in the past?
- What device are you using, and what Android system is it running?
- What fonts have you tried so far? (font names)
- When you say "everywhere", do you only refer to keyboards or texts as well?

Comment: No I haven't seen them correctly in the past. My device is infinix hot 8. I have tried the fonts provided by infinix fonts. Everywhere in the app termux where it is showing errors in the first place.